# getting error while installing watir gem on ruby193

Tags: ruby, watir

```
C:\Ruby193>gem install watir
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
Invalid argument - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mini_magick-3.6.0/tes
t/files/special! "chars'.gif
```

**error while installing ruby gem.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the mini_magick gem - see [Issue 145](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/145). While the issue has been fixed, a new release not yet been released.

You can try getting the unreleased version of mini_magick, though it is probably easier to just use the older version.

Manually install mini_magick (previous version), then install watir:

```
gem install mini_magick -v 3.5
gem install watir
```